# How to improve throughput with FileStream in a single-threaded application

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, .net-4.5, ntfs, c#-5.0

I am trying to get top I/O performance in a data streaming application with eight SSDs in RAID-5 (each SSD advertises and delivers 500 MB/sec reads).

I create FileStream with 64KB buffer and read many blocks in a blocking fashion (pun not intended).  Here's what I have now with 80GB in 20K files, no fragments:
Legacy blocking reads are at 1270 MB/sec with single thread, 1556 MB/sec with 6 threads.

What I noticed with single-thread is that a single core's worth of CPU time is spent in kernel (8.3% red in Process Explorer with 12 cores).  With 6 threads, approximately 5x CPU time is spent in kernel (41% red in in Process Explorer with 12 cores).

I would really like to avoid complexity of a multi-threaded application in the I/O bound scenario.

Is it possible to achieve these transfer rates in a single-threaded application?  That is, what would be a good way to reduce the amount of time in kernel mode?

How, if at all, would the new Async feature in C# help?

For comparison, [ATTO disk benchmark](http://www.attotech.com/products/product.php?sku=Disk_Benchmark) shows 2500 MB/sec at these block sizes on this hardware and low CPU utilization.  However, ATTO dataset size is mere 2GB.

Using [LSI 9265-8i](http://www.lsi.com/products/storagecomponents/Pages/MegaRAIDSAS9265-8i.aspx) RAID controller, with 64k stripe size, 64k cluster size.

[image: image1]

[image: summary image]

[image: i/o counts]

[image: QD10]

[image: ATTO Single request]

Here's a sketch of the code in use.  I don't write production code this way, it's just a proof of concept.

```
   volatile bool _somethingLeftToRead = false;
   long _totalReadInSize = 0;
   void ProcessReadThread(object obj)
   {
      TestThreadJob job = obj as TestThreadJob;
      var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(job.InFilePath);
      int chunk = job.DataBatchSize * 1024;

      //var tile = new List<byte[]>();

      var sw = new Stopwatch();

      var allFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles();

      var fileStreams = new List<FileStream>();
      long totalSize = 0;
      _totalReadInSize = 0;

      foreach (var fileInfo in allFiles)
      {
         totalSize += fileInfo.Length;
         var fileStream = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName,
             FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, job.FileBufferSize * 1024);

         fileStreams.Add(fileStream);
      }

      var partial = new byte[chunk];
      var taskParam = new TaskParam(null, partial);
      var tasks = new List<Task>();
      int numTasks = (int)Math.Ceiling(fileStreams.Count * 1.0 / job.NumThreads);
      sw.Start();

      do
      {
         _somethingLeftToRead = false;

         for (int taskIndex = 0; taskIndex < numTasks; taskIndex++)
         {
            if (_threadCanceled)
               break;
            tasks.Clear();
            for (int thread = 0; thread < job.NumThreads; thread++)
            {
               if (_threadCanceled)
                  break;
               int fileIndex = taskIndex * job.NumThreads + thread;
               if (fileIndex >= fileStreams.Count)
                  break;
               var fileStream = fileStreams[fileIndex];

               taskParam.File = fileStream;
               if (job.NumThreads == 1)
                  ProcessFileRead(taskParam);
               else
                  tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(ProcessFileRead, taskParam));

               //tile.Add(partial);
            }
            if (_threadCanceled)
               break;
            if (job.NumThreads > 1)
               Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
         }

         //tile = new List<byte[]>();
      }
      while (_somethingLeftToRead);

      sw.Stop();

      foreach (var fileStream in fileStreams)
         fileStream.Close();

      totalSize = (long)Math.Round(totalSize / 1024.0 / 1024.0);
      UpdateUIRead(false, totalSize, sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
   }

   void ProcessFileRead(object taskParam)
   {
      TaskParam param = taskParam as TaskParam;
      int readInSize;
      if ((readInSize = param.File.Read(param.Bytes, 0, param.Bytes.Length)) != 0)
      {
         _somethingLeftToRead = true;
         _totalReadInSize += readInSize;
      }
   }
```

Comment: SSD seek times are *much* better than HDDs but you can't ignore them.  Typ is 0.1 to 0.3 msec, still a very long time in cpu cycles.  Having a bunch of threads fighting over the controller, waiting for a data access to complete and forcing it to seek will not get you ATTO numbers.  I doubt you ever will with 20K files, 1650 sounds good to me.

Comment: Seems that I am leaving a lot of perf on the table.  Each SSD is rated at 500 MB/sec read, so 7 of them should get me to 3.5 GB/sec, right?

Comment: By the way, this is over 8 channels of SATA 6Gb/sec; RAID card is plugged in to x8 PCIe 2.0.

Comment: @HansPassant I suspect NTFS, but can't prove it.

Comment: http://thessdreview.com/our-reviews/sata-3/lsi-sas-9207-8i-pcie-3-0-host-bus-adapter-quick-preview/5/

Comment: Can you show us the C# code?

Comment: Try 2 things: 1) Choose a large block size (4 MB) to have less IOs and therefore less CPU usage. 2) Write a simple single-threaded reading loop in a few lines just to make sure that your loop does not contain any performance bug (it is to complex for me to mentally verify).

Comment: Not sure what I would write. Did my suggestions help?

Comment: @usr I am in agreement with my colleagues that Direct I/O can be helpful in this scenario.  Trying it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of issues here.

First, I see that you are not trying to use non-cached I/O.  This means that the system will try to cache your data in RAM and service reads out of it. SO you get an extra data transfer out of things.  Do non-cached I/O.

Next, you appear to be creating/destroying threads inside a loop.  This is inefficient.

Lastly, you need to investigate the alignment of the data.  Crossing read-block boundaries can add to your costs.

I would advocate using non-cached, async I/O.  I'm not sure how to accomplish this in C# (but it should be easy).

EDITED: Also, why are you using RAID 5?  Unless the data is write-once, this is likely to have hideous performance on SSDs. Notably, the erase block size is typically 512K, meaning when you write something smaller, the SSD will need to read the 512K in its firmware, change the data, and then write it somewhere else.  You might want to make the stripe size = size of erase block.  Also, you should check to see what the alignment of the writes are as well.

Comment: Could you also elaborate on why exactly cached reads are bad for overall performance of a streaming application?  You might be onto something, but I don't quite follow.

Comment: The premise behind caching is that it is faster to read data out of memory than from the device.  So, for the 2nd...nth access to the data, keeping it in memory is usually a good tradeoff as your aggregate performance is roughly

Comment: n * memory copy plus one disk transfer.  But this is for REPEATED reads.  

If you read the data once (typical of read-once streaming), you pay for an extra memory copy (from the cache to the user buffer) and you pay for the memory (typically by evicting other data).

It all depends on what your expected usage pattern is going to be.